# Nextcord levelling system

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I want to add a levelling system to my nextcord bot. My actual cog looks like this:

```py
from nextcord.ext import commands
import nextcord
import json
import random

class Level(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    async def update_data(self, users, user,server):
        if not str(server.id) in users:
            users[str(server.id)] = {}
            if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
                users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
                users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]["experience"] = 0
                users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]["level"] = 1
        elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]["level"] = 1

    async def add_experience(self, users, user, exp, server):
        users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]["experience"] += exp

    async def level_up(self, users, user, channel, server):
        experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]["experience"]
        lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]["level"]
        lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
        if str(user.guild.id) != "896366068417830933":
            if lvl_start < lvl_end:
                channel = self.bot.get_channel(937531195636457502)
                embed = nextcord.Embed(title=f"GG {user.name}! Tu es maintenant niveau {lvl_end}")
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]["level"] = lvl_end

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot:
            with open("users.json",'r') as f:
                users = json.load(f)
            xp = random.randint(1, 3)
            await update_data(users, message.author,message.guild)
            await add_experience(users, message.author, xp, message.guild)
            await level_up(users, message.author,message.channel, message.guild)
            with open('level.json','w') as f:
                json.dump(users, f, indent=2)
        await self.bot.process_commands(message)
  
    @commands.command()
    async def level(self, ctx, member: nextcord.Member=None):
        if not member:
            user = ctx.message.author
            with open("users.json", "r") as f:
                users = json.load(f)
            lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]["level"]
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title=f"Tu es niveau {lvl}", color = nextcord.Color.blue())
            embed.set_author(name=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            with open("users.jspn", "r") as f:
                users = json.load(f)
            lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]["level"]
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title=f"{member.mention} est niveau {lvl}", color=nextcord.Color.blue())
            embed.set_author(name=member, icon_url=member.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Level(bot))
```

**keep in mind that there's nothing in the json file**

I don't know why, it isn't working properly. When I send a message in discord, it's sending this in the console/output:
[image]

so, how can I fix it? Is there any improvment that I could do in the cog?

Comment: I feel like you just answered your own question. What happens if you do `json.loads('')`? If the json file is empty and its trying to load an empty string, you're going to get that error.

Comment: well, it's normal that it's empty because the bot won't write in it

Comment: Try the following, it's simple yet accomplishes what a levelling bot needs. Recommended by nextcord developer. https://pypi.org/project/levelling/